# Why is my file not being read in, even though its path is the same as another project where the file is read in successfully?

Tags: java, eclipse, inputstream, filereader

//This is where I read in my file

```
String fileName = "crimedata-full-month.csv";
    
    FileReader file = new FileReader(fileName);
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
```

//This is the error I get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: crimedata-full-month.csv (No such file or directory)
at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:216)
at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:157)
at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:111)
at java.base/java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:60)
at Crimes.main(Crimes.java:56)
```

[This is the path it follows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J68Bw.png)

I'm running this in Eclipse on my MacBook.

Comment: By default, the working directory is the project folder (which can be changed in the launch configuration in the tab _Arguments_). So you have to use `"src/crimedata-full-month.csv"` or `"bin/crimedata-full-month.csv"`. But better use [`getResourceAsStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) instead of a File/FileReader because that will also work when exporting it to a JAR file.

Comment: If you don't specify a path for the file then Java looks for it in the current working directory - which is usually not the 'src' directory.